# How to check your model has no errors in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

An a interviewer asked me what is the command to check your model has no errors.

Does Django have any type of command like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly run the checks with the [`check`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#check) command:

```
python manage.py check
```

To specifically check the models, you can do:

```
python manage.py check --tag models
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the makemigrations command will return any errors on the model. At least that's where I find that I forgot a default value for required fields, etc.

Comment: i says the same answer to interviewer but he refused my answer